# SQL Server: comparing two tables, two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

- `TableA` (`ID int, Match1 char, Match2 char, status char`)
- `TableB` (`Match1 char, match2`)

I want to flag rows in `tableA` as fail in status where for same `match1, match2` do not exist in `tableB`.

Example:

**TableA**

```
ID Match1 Match2 Status
1   100    AB    
2   100    AR
3   200    BC
4   200    VB
5   200    AB
```

**TableB**

```
Match1 Match2
100     AF
100     AR
100     BG
200     AB
200     BJ
200     VB
```

Expected result:

**TableA**

```
ID Match1 Match2 Status
1   100    AB    FAIL 
2   100    AR    NULL
3   200    BC    FAIL
4   200    VB    NULL
5   200    AB    NULL
```

Thanks

I used(not working):

```
Update A
set status = 'FAIL'
from TableA A
  Inner join TableB B
  ON A.match1 = B.match1
  WHERE A.match2 <> B.Match2
```

Comment: Why didn't it work?  Did you get an error message?  If not, did you get unexpected output?  If so, what was it?

Comment: It is failing all the records in tableA

Comment: marc_s: It a totally different question !

Comment: Try using UPDATE TableA SET...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE a
    SET status = 'FAIL'
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM TableB b
                         WHERE a.match1 = b.match1
                             AND a.match2 = b.match2)
```

Comment: what is "a"? please explain

Comment: did exactly but it said #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM TableA a WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM T' at line 3

Comment: @John 1) "a" is an alias for TableA, 2) this answer was specifically intended for SQL Server. MySQL does not support this form of UPDATE and 3) I hope you did not downvote this answer because you tried to take it out of context.

Comment: I modified it to UPDATE TableA a SET status = 'FAIL' WHERE NOT ExISTS(...) and it worked. Hope that I can revote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ID INT, Match1 VARCHAR(10), Match2 VARCHAR(10), MatchStatus VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TableA(ID, Match1, Match2) 
VALUES(1, '100', 'AB'), (2, '100', 'AR'), (3, '200', 'BC'), (4, '200', 'VB'), (5, '200', 'AB')

DECLARE @TableB TABLE (Match1 VARCHAR(10), Match2 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES('100', 'AF'), ('100', 'AR'), ('100', 'BG'), ('200', 'AB'),
('200', 'BJ'), ('200', 'VB')

UPDATE @TableA
SET MatchStatus = 'FAIL'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT * FROM @TableB b 
           WHERE b.Match1 = [@TableA].Match1 AND b.Match2 = [@TableA].Match2)

SELECT * FROM @TableA
```

Gives me an output of:

```
ID  Match1  Match2  MatchStatus
 1   100     AB       FAIL
 2   100     AR       NULL
 3   200     BC       FAIL
 4   200     VB       NULL
 5   200     AB       NULL
```